# Scrolling down to the next div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сan't get scroll down working in my jquery script:

```
jQuery('.overlay_'+onderzoekid).css("background", "green"); 
jQuery('.check_'+onderzoekid).each(function() 
{
    this.checked = true;  
});
```

If this checked is `true` go to next overlay div.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your element is checked using jquery `is(':checked')` and if true scroll to related overlay with this element using `scrollTop` :

```
jQuery('.check_'+onderzoekid).each(function() 
{
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
        $('html, body').animate({
            'scrollTop' : jQuery('.overlay_'+onderzoekid).position().top
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.